# DNS and MVC 5 routing (Internet vs Internal Lan)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dns, asp.net-mvc-routing

I know there are many helps on MVC 5, but I have not seen the following question answered.

My application works fine on the local LAN...  I can access using expected URL:
       http://www.mycompany.com/myapp

However when I try to access the server over the INTERNET I can't access the application via the hostname, only via the external IP address:
           http://xx.xx.xx.xx/myapp

I have talked to the firewall / DNS admin people and the assure me that it is an application problem.   We are using GoDaddy to handle DNS.    The admin has setup and A record to point to the server, but after working with GoDaddy they have setup subdomains as the way to access applications...

They have another Internet application (that uses asp.net) working using the following URL:
              http://appname.companyName.com

This is the way they expect my application to route on the Internet...

I am using just the standard default MVC routes... since my application routes correctly on the local lan I assumed the problem is with the DNS ... and the admin people say it is an MVC problem...

So what is the problem and what is the solution?  Are the DNS / Firewall admin poeple right?  Is this an issue caused by my MVC routing?

Here is my standard RouteConfig.cs file... I don't have anything special setup...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace EtracsWeb
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a DNS problem, not an MVC problem. There is nothing your MVC routing configuration can do to solve this.

Comment: That was my understanding... As I understand it the MVC routing tables ONLY apply to routes within an application... They would have no impact on the base address... in this case the http://appname.companyname.come ... Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You need to configure a DNS server to resolve the name to an IP address.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem, but even on local LAN, when trying to access a MVC app via it's IP. It is returning a 404. So it seems that the IP address comes to the right server, and IIS does respond. Could you connect? Did you resolve the problem in the end?

Comment: I have found my problem BTW, a host name was assigned in IIS, and then entering by IP won't resolve to the site.